# Show that $S_n$ has no subgroup of index $t$ for $2 < t < n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I am trying to solve the following exercise

> Show that $S_n$ has no subgroup of index $t$ for $2 < t < n$

which is the exercise 3.25 of [An Introduction to Theory of Groups](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-4176-8), by Joseph J. Rotman.

I think I should use a theorem that says that if $H \le G$ and $[G : H] = \ell$, then $\exists \rho \in \mathrm{Hom}(G, S_\ell)$ such that $\ker(\rho) \le H$.  That would give me an isomorphism between $S_n / \langle \ker(\rho) \rangle $ and $\mathrm{Im}(\rho) \le S_t$ and I was hoping to prove that it is impossible.

I tried to fix some value for $t$, for instance, $t = 3$, to have some idea about the general problem, but even in this scenario, I am not able to prove it, because I can't visualize the group $S_n / \langle \ker(\rho) \rangle $.

Well, do you have any tip? I am not looking for a full answer to that exercise, but maybe you could point out some theorems and properties of $S_n$ that might be useful here.

Comment: It would give you an isomorphism between $S_n/\ker\rho$ and ${\rm im}\,\rho$ (the image being a subgroup of $S_t$). Anyway, can you use the fact $S_n$'s only normal subgroups are $A_n$ (except $n=4$)?

Comment: @anon  Sure, it should be the image of rho. I have edited the question. And yes, I can use it.

Answer (score 3):

Theorem 3.14 is used often in solving exercises in Rotman's Introduction to the Theory of Groups.  In this application, we are looking for a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $t=[G:H]>2$.  There is a homomorphism $\rho: G\rightarrow S_t$ with $\text{ker}\;\rho \le H$.  $\text{ker}\;\rho$ is a normal subgroup of $S_5$ with an index that is greater than 2.  But, $A_5$ is the only non-trivial normal subgroup of $S_5$, so $\text{ker}\;\rho=1$ and $t=n$.

Answer (score 2):

Using google gave this question here, where someone claimed that he has found a proof:
[A subgroup of symmetric group of degree n with index smaller than n.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131619/a-subgroup-of-symmetric-group-of-degree-n-with-index-smaller-than-n)

The basic idea is to use the theorem you gave, together with the fact that a kernel of a homomorphism is normal and the only non-trivial normal subgroup of $S_n$ is $A_n$ (for $n \geq 5$, so you might need to do the case $n = 4$ and $t = 3$ by hand).

Comment: Any idea for the special case? That is $n = 4$ and $t=3$?